# taking partial derivative of a sum

Tags: summation, partial-derivative

I want to take the partial derivative d/d$\mu$ of the following sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{x_i}$

Looking to keep the $\sum_{x=1}^n (x_i-\mu)$ in the result.

what happens to the $x_i$ when partially differentiating such a sum?

Comment: $\newcommand{\pd}{\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}}$ $\pd$ is linear, so $\pd\sum_{i = 1}^nf_i(\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^n\pd f_i(\mu)$, so you just need to calculate $\pd f_i(\mu)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac\partial{\partial \mu} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{x_i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{-2(x_i - \mu)}{x_i}$$